# If in Loop in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

This should be an incredibly easy question but I am not very familiar with bash and I am taking way longer than I should to figure it out.

```
declare -a ids=( 1 2 3 )
for i in "${ids[@]}";
do
  re= $(mysql -h .... "SELECT col_A FROM DBA WHERE id=$i")
  if [ $re -eq 0 ]; then
     echo sucess
  fi
done
```

This is an example of what I am trying to do, I have an id array and I want to send a query to my db so I can get a flag in the row with a certain id and then do something based on that. But I keep getting unexpected token errors and I am not entirely sure why

Edit: While copying the code and deleting some private information somehow I deleted the then, it was present in the code I was testing.

Comment: delete the space in `re= $`

Comment: the loop is clearly irrelevant.

Comment: Also, where's the `then`?

Comment: As you might have noticed, you are getting negative votes on your question. This is mostly because your question title does not accurately match your question. You might should revise the question title to something more like "Bash syntax and unexpected token error". Also, people people are expecting you to do a little more research and work before posting a question. In the future, I would suggest using http://www.shellcheck.net/ to help you perform basic reviews of your shell script before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described and the partial script, I am not certain I can completely create what you are trying to do but the token error messages you are experiencing usually have to do with the way `bash` handles whitespace as a delimiter. A few comments based on what you posted:

1. You need to remove the space around the equal sign in declaring an variable, so the space after the equal sign in `re=` needs to removed.
2. Because `bash` will is sensitive to whitespace, you need to quote variables declarations that might contain a space. To be safe, quotes need to be around the sub-shell `$( )`
3. You were missing the `then` in the `if` statement
4. It is important that variables in the test brackets, that is single [ ]s, must be quoted. Using an unquoted string with `-eq`, or even just the unquoted string alone within test brackets *normally works*, however, this is an *unsafe practice* and can give unpredictable results.

So, taking into account the items noted, the updated script would look something like:

```
declare -a ids=( 1 2 3 )
for i in "${ids[@]}";
do
  re="$(mysql -h .... "SELECT col_A FROM DBA WHERE id=$i")"
  if [ "$re" -eq "0" ]; then
     echo "success"
  fi
done
```

Can you try working the edits mentioned into your script and see if you are able to get it working? Remember, it will be helpful for you to use a site like [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to learn more about potential pitfalls or the uniquenesses of `bash` syntax. This will help to ensure you are working toward a solution to your specific need rather then getting trapped by some tricky syntax.

After you have worked through those edits, can you report back your experience?

**EDIT**

Based on your comments there is a good chance you are not running your script with bash despite the including `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script. When you run the script as `sh scriptname.sh` you are forcing the script to be run by `sh` not `bash`. Try running your script like this `/bin/bash scriptname.sh` then report back on your experience.

For more information on the differences between various `shell`s, see [Unix/Linux : Difference between sh , csh , ksh and bash Shell](http://www.techmagazinez.com/2013/12/unixlinux-difference-between-sh-csh-ksh.html)

Comment: Did those changes, still got the unexpected sintax token near do.

Comment: Also ShellCheck says everything is fine.

Comment: Based on what you saying, it is very hard to troubleshoot this for you. I think there must be an error elsewhere in your script or you are somehow using another `shell` other than `bash`. A few things that might help us help you: How are you running your script? Do you have a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script? What is the exact error you are getting when you run the script now?

Comment: I am running, the script on my unix terminal by calling "sh filename.sh", I do have  #!/bin/bash, the exact error is "unexpected sintax token `do"

Comment: Then you are probably not using bash to run the script. Try `/bin/bash filename.sh`

Comment: Ups, that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with your if statement is that you do not have the `then` keyword. A simple fix is:

```
declare -a ids=( 1 2 3 )
for i in "${ids[@]}";
do
    re= $(mysql -h .... "SELECT col_A FROM DBA WHERE id=$i")
    if [ $re -eq 0 ]; then
       echo sucess
    fi
       done
```

Also here is a great [reference](http://bencane.com/2014/01/27/8-examples-of-bash-if-statements-to-get-you-started/) on if statements in bash